# Spring Tool Suite 3.4.0.RELEASE and html / jsp formatting

Tags: java, eclipse, html, jsp

I'm not an eclipse user and I'm forced to use Eclipse / STS 3.4.0 for my project, so maybe I'm missing something...

I have several jsp in my webapp, that have been perfectly formatted from another tool.

For example, I start from this jsp "unhautorized.jsp" :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
   <head>
       <title>NO ACCESS page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Oops !</h1>

      <p>You should not be here !</p>
   </body> 
</html>
```

After a Source > code format, I get this :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy, see www.w3.org">
<title>NO ACCESS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Oops !</h1>

    <p>You should not be here !</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Html indentation is completely wrecked outside of the body tag.

What am I missing? Some specific plugin ? I searched through configurations panels, but found nothing to solve this inacceptable UN-formatting of my original sources.